# Paypal sandbox return "500:Internal Server Error"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

When I use the link on paypal developer to access paypal sandbox, the page return the message  "500:Internal Server Error". If anyone can provide any advise.

Best Regards

Comment: Are you talking the general http://sandbox.paypal.com URL or the API endpoints for the sandbox?  If the endpoint, which one specifically are you using?

Comment: Hi  Andrew, thank you for your reply, it seems ok now. But when I first enter "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" it returned me a 500 error

Comment: This is probably a PayPal bug, and should be reported to them. On the other hand, if it is a bug with the user's code, the question is unanswerable without that code being provided.

Comment: I have same problem, when trying to create payment without parameters